# Looking for feedback on my sound re-design...

Tags: sound-design

This is my sound re-design of a cool video game trailer.  I yanked the audio track and completely re-designed all the sound.  I used the signal generator in Pro Tools and audio from a short recording session in my garage.  I'd like to get some feedback...what I did right/wrong/weird/cool.  Used some drills, screws dropped on cement, me kicking my garage door and more.  Vimeo link below.  Thanks!

http://www.vimeo.com/23530894

Answer (score 1):

this is great, thou few minuses in my opinion, that are basically a matter of taste...

first, "music" felt a little bit repetitive...
second, robot(geth, or whatever...i cant remember their race name :) ) at the end...it has these mechanisms on his head, also a lens in his eye, that is a great visual material to make sound for (thou i noticed that you did almost the same sound as in original trailer)..

ok, the good thing is that i really like your version of glitches and letters typing/appearing over the original trailer ;)

p.s.: sorry for my not so very good english ;)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words and critique!  More to think about.  With the music I kind of wanted a creepy bell toll effect...but yeah, repetitive.  On the head mechanisms I wanted a sliding metal as opposed to servos/motors...just the feeling I got watching it move.  Glitches and letters are my favorite part too.  Thanks again for the kind words and constructive criticism!

Answer (score 1):

WOW! Well done. Love the glitch sounds, and the text as @Linas mentioned. I also like how everything goes quiet after "KILLED IN ACTION" for a moment.

I did find that the robot at the end was a little low in volume, would have liked to have heard more as the energy comes on, and the servos kick in, leading to the flare.  Also I probably would have gone for more crescendo in the score at that point to REALLY kick the audience in the pants for the big reveal. That's the point you can really play with dynamics, building up to loud and then having it all go away as the name comes up. BUT... those are more taste/aesthetic things.

Comment: Thanks!  Great points!  I might play with it some more.  I went with a little more quiet, subdued mood.  I had some good servo motor sounds but I kind of had the vision of steel/metal sliding against each other rather than focusing on the servos.  But like you said, just taste/aesthetics.  Thanks again for the great comments!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what's already been said about the metallic/scrape element ("music"), it's a bit repetitive and dulls the flow of the piece. It's texture is great though!

If you wanted to rework that element, I'd say to mess with the duration/timing of the phrases, change the frequency content, and apply some additional filtering every now and then. Give that piece of your design some movement and life, and it will really help your pacing.